# C# copy string to byte buffer

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am trying to copy an Ascii string to a byte array but am unable. How?

---

Here are the two things I have tried so far. Neither one works:

```
public int GetString (ref byte[] buffer, int buflen)
{
    string mystring = "hello world";

    // I have tried this:
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    buffer = encoding.GetBytes(mystring);

    // and tried this:
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(mystring.ToCharArray(), 0, buffer, 0, buflen);  
   return (buflen);
}
```

Comment: What does "neither one works" mean? What's the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the buffer is big enough, you can just write it directly:

```
encoding.GetBytes(mystring, 0, mystring.Length, buffer, 0)
```

However, you might need to check the length first; a test might be:

```
if(encoding.GetMaxByteCount(mystring.length) <= buflen // cheapest first
   || encoding.GetByteCount(mystring) <= buflen)
{
    return encoding.GetBytes(mystring, 0, mystring.Length, buffer, 0)
}
else
{
    buffer = encoding.GetBytes(mystring);
    return buffer.Length;
}
```

after that, there is **nothing to do**, since you are already passing `buffer` out by `ref`. Personally, I *suspect* that this `ref` is a bad choice, though. There is no need to `BlockCopy` here, unless you were copying from a scratch buffer, i.e.

```
var tmp = encoding.GetBytes(mystring);
// copy as much as we can from tmp to buffer
Buffer.BlockCopy(tmp, 0, buffer, 0, buflen);
return buflen;
```

Comment: Thanks, Marc, but I get this error: "error CS0103: The name 'encoding' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Neilw that came from your question... `System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();` (although to be fair, `var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;` would be easier)

Comment: Doh! That woked. Just a misspelling. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This one will deal with creating the byte buffer:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Jabberwocky");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody needs standard c code function like strcpy convert to c#

```
    void strcpy(ref byte[] ar,int startpoint,string str)
    {
        try
        {
            int position = startpoint;
            byte[] tempb = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
            for (int i = 0; i < tempb.Length; i++)
            {
                ar[position] = tempb[i];
                position++;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ER: "+ex.Message);
        }

    }
```