# How to convert utf8 string to utf8 byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8

How can I convert string to utf8 byte array, I have this sample code:

This works ok:

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(file1, false, Encoding.UTF8);
file.WriteLine(utf8string);
file.Close();
```

This works wrong, file is in ASCII:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(utf8string);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(file2, FileMode.CreateNew);
fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
fs.Close();
```

I would like to get byte array what returned by this function:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path_to_file)
```

because this works ok:

```
byte[] datab = File.ReadAllBytes(file1);
FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(file3, FileMode.CreateNew);
fs2.Write(datab, 0, datab.Length);
fs2.Close();
```

Comment: Why do you think your second example doesn't work?

Comment: Very similar question just asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539559/c-sharp-copy-string-to-byte-buffer

Comment: Does this not answer your question `byte[] bytes = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(utf8string);`?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Can use other option again:

```
string value = "\u00C4 \uD802\u0033 \u00AE";    
byte[] bytes= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
```

For more information can look on [Encoding.UTF8 Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Gb/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx)

Comment: Does the resulting byte array contain a trailing NULL character?

Comment: Only if the input array has one. It's a one-for-one copy.